# java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.TextImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, weblogic

I get this java.lang.ClassCastException by trying to communicate with my Webservice which has SOAPHeader Handler implimentation.

The error occurs by

```
String data= ((Text) ((SOAPElement) is.next()).getChildElements().next()).getValue();
```

in the incomming method this class "`oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.TextImpl`"

I can not explain from where it comes i didn't bind it anywhere

**NOTE

1. I'am using Weblogic Server 12c

2. I search after TextImpl class in the hole server but no result**

May be somebody faces already this issue?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had similar problem when i deployed my web service into IBM WAS7.0 and tested through SOAP UI. After so much of google search i came to know the root case

"issue was that whitespace in the header was incorrectly being cast to a SOAPElement which resulted in the ClassCastException."

After removed the white space in the SOAP request, it worked.

Refer the link for more information http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK90295

Check if there is a similar issue in WebLogic too.

Comment: The same thing happens with soapUI 5.1.2 and WebLogic 12.1. Removing the whitespace between elements of the request in the soapUI editor does the trick.